# Reference ViewModel's DataContext from within a DataTemplate in a DataTemplate

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, mvvm, windows-phone-8

I found myself in a bit of a bind... with bindings... hehe... (lame)

Anyway... I need to refer to the main ViewModel's Property, but from within a `DataTemplate`, which is itself within another `DataTemplate`... and it looks like the only `RelativeSource` mode that Silverlight allows are: Self and TemplatedParent. And TemplatedParent doesn't go up enough.

Is there anything that can be done?

Some code:

```
<phone:PanoramaItem>
    <phone:LongListSelector Margin="0,-38,-22,2" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <common:ItemContentTemplateSelector DataContext="{Binding}" Content="{Binding ItemContent}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="12,2,0,4">
                    <common:ItemContentTemplateSelector.DefaultTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            .....
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </common:ItemContentTemplateSelector.DefaultTemplate>
                    <common:ItemContentTemplateSelector.PhoneNumberTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Background="White" Height="102">
                                <Border x:Name="border">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Call"/>
                                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                                     <!-- BINDING ERROR -->
                                            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=DataContext.PhoneCallCommand}"/>
                                        </i:EventTrigger>
                                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                </Border>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </common:ItemContentTemplateSelector.PhoneNumberTemplate>
                </common:ItemContentTemplateSelector>
            </DataTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector>
</phone:PanoramaItem>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't wont a workaround or make it easily,
There is something to do;

Using StaticResource

have a look at this;

```
   MyViewModelClass ViewModel
   {
        get;set;
   }

  ...ctor()
  {
     this.ViewModel=new MyViewModelClass();
     this.DataContext=this.ViewModel; //We use same VM instance as DataContext as Resource
     this.Resoureces.Add("MainVieModel",ViewModel);
     InitializeComponents();//...Add resource before this line
  }
```

After that you can use your ViewModel at the same time as a StaticResource anywhere you want;

```
{Binding Path=Items,Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}
```

I coded on stackoverflow's editor. There could be some missing chars ...

Comment: Nice workaround! Thanks! Is it possible to add this static resource in XAML only?

Comment: I have been using this workaround for years. Do you mean Adding this resource on XAML side? Yes , you may do that. You may add datacontext in xaml also. Something like that `<UserControl.Resources><local:MyViewModelClass x:Key="MainVieModel"/><UserControl.Resources>`

Comment: Notice my comment in the code `//We use samve VM instace...` doing it is not easy cause of xaml rendering order,instance creation order have a look for it at http://stackoverflow.com/q/10171630/413032 Doing it in codebehind seems better for now.