# XAML TemplateBinding within a DataTemplate

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp

I'm creating a templated control for a UWP app, and I've hit a snag when trying to bind within a nested DataTemplate. Here's my control XAML in Themes/Generic.xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="local:EnhancedListView">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:EnhancedListView">
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <DataTemplate x:Key="ListViewTemplate">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition />
                                    <ColumnDefinition />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <CheckBox Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, Path=IsCheckModeEnabled}" Grid.Column="0" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Grid.Column="1" />
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Grid.Resources>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <CheckBox Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, Path=IsCheckModeEnabled}" Grid.Row="0">Hello</CheckBox>
                    <ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListViewTemplate}" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Here's my actual control/converter:

```
public class EnhancedListView : Control
{
    public EnhancedListView()
    {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof(EnhancedListView);
    }

    public object ItemsSource
    {
        get { return GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(object), typeof(EnhancedListView), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public bool IsCheckModeEnabled
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsCheckModeEnabledProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsCheckModeEnabledProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCheckModeEnabledProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsCheckModeEnabled", typeof(bool), typeof(EnhancedListView), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}

public class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return (bool)value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Here's the MainPage.xaml:

```
<local:EnhancedListView IsCheckModeEnabled="False" x:Name="ctlListView">
</local:EnhancedListView>
```

And finally, my MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        ctlListView.ItemsSource = new List<string> { "Item 1", "Item 2" };
    }
```

As I would expect, when the page loads, the first checkbox is hidden because IsCheckModeEnabled is false, but all the checkboxes nested within the DataTemplate are still visible.

I've tried wrapping this into a StaticResource as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18265278/reference-viewmodels-datacontext-from-within-a-datatemplate-in-a-datatemplate), but it doesn't work with some complex types, such as nesting another DataTemplate within my DataTemplate.

I'm certain the binding isn't quite right on the Visibility property here:

`<CheckBox Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, Path=IsCheckModeEnabled}" Grid.Column="0" />`

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, it's impossible to know for sure what the problem is, never mind the best fix. But it looks as though you mistakenly believe that the templated parent of an item in a `ListView` is the same as the templated parent of the template containing that `ListView`. If that's not enough to point you in the right direction, please improve your question.

Comment: And where's the sense in writing `DataContext="{Binding}"`?

Comment: @PeterDuniho - I added additional details to improve the question. I also don't "mistakenly believe" that the template parent of the `ListView` item is the same as the parent container, I just don't know how to represent it and bind to it.

Comment: @Clemens - It's important for my final product to get the entire object bound as part of the CheckBox. I removed that from my example.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but how about this:

```
<CheckBox Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=local:EnhancedListView}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, Path=IsCheckModeEnabled}" DataContext="{Binding}" Grid.Column="0" />
```

btw: man this is convoluted...

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that doesn't seem to work as AncestorType is not valid: `Unknown member 'AncestorType' on element 'RelativeSource'`

Comment: another suggestion, have you tried playing with ListViews SelectionMode = multiple? I could imagine a Style that enables checkboxes when this mode is applied...

Comment: taking a look at it (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299136.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) the standard listviewitem does have checkboxes, so if you enable multi selection they should be visible. why not go that way?

Comment: Yes, it does, but there are additional things I'm trying to support as well. The checkbox example is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do but the same problem exists; being unable to bind to something from the TemplatedParent from within the DataTemplate.

Comment: Since this is UWP you don't even have access to an inheritable attached property so I'd say you best bet is to have your main ViewModel have a Property `IsCheckModeEnabled` and have the ListView's Items ViewModels have a `Parent` Property to access that main ViewModel and then use a `DataTemplate` that contains a `CheckBox`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was aiming for a little more reusability that could be applied across the app. I think I found a solution that doesn't involve changing the data source/view model (above).

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found a "cleaner" solution that works. I created a new `EnhancedListViewItem` class which can mimic the properties on the `EnhancedListView.` Then I assign and style that `EnhancedListViewItem` independently from the parent `EnhancedListView.` Here's my updated Generic.xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="local:EnhancedListView">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:EnhancedListView">
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <CheckBox Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, Path=IsCheckModeEnabled}" Grid.Column="0" />
                    <ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="local:EnhancedListViewDataItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:EnhancedListViewDataItem">
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <CheckBox Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, Path=IsCheckModeEnabled}" Grid.Column="0" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Grid.Column="1" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And here's my updated code behind for the controls:

```
public class EnhancedListView : Control, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public EnhancedListView()
    {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof(EnhancedListView);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public object ItemsSource
    {
        get { return GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set
        {
            var boundItems = new List<EnhancedListViewDataItem>();

            foreach (var obj in (List<string>)value)
            {
                boundItems.Add(new EnhancedListViewDataItem(this)
                {
                    DataContext = obj
                });
            }

            SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, boundItems);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(object), typeof(EnhancedListView), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public bool IsCheckModeEnabled
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsCheckModeEnabledProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(IsCheckModeEnabledProperty, value);
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsCheckModeEnabled"));
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCheckModeEnabledProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsCheckModeEnabled", typeof(bool), typeof(EnhancedListView), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}

public class EnhancedListViewDataItem : ListViewItem
{
    public EnhancedListViewDataItem(EnhancedListView listView)
    {
        _listView = listView;
        _listView.PropertyChanged += _listView_PropertyChanged;
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof(EnhancedListViewDataItem);
    }

    private readonly EnhancedListView _listView;

    private void _listView_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsCheckModeEnabled = _listView.IsCheckModeEnabled;
    }

    public bool IsCheckModeEnabled
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsCheckModeEnabledProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsCheckModeEnabledProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCheckModeEnabledProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsCheckModeEnabled", typeof(bool), typeof(EnhancedListViewDataItem), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```